# Why C# gRPC client taking more than 2 minutes to connect with server for the first call in Linux Debian OS

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#

I have developed C# gRPC client in Console application. I run the below code in windows, when executing **var reply = client.SetImage(new ImageMessage() { Ok = img });** taking 20 seconds to receive ack from server but when i run the same code Linux Debian OS taking 2 mins to establish connection with server (here build is generated in Visual Studio with debian.11-x64), here second calls are taking 2ms.

can anyone tell me why taking much time in Linux Debian OS for the first call and how to solve this?

```
`public class GrpcChannelFactory
    {
        public static GrpcChannel GetGrpcChannel()
        {
            var channelOption = new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                MaxReceiveMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxSendMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            };

            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
            var address = "http://localhost:3131";
            return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, channelOption);
        }
    }

public void SendImageTest(byte[] imageData, int frameRowSize, int frameColSize, int numberOfFrames, int numberOfIteration)
        {
            if (channel == null
                channel = GrpcChannelFactory.GetGrpcChannel();

            var client = new ImageReceiver.ImageReceiverClient(channel);

            Image img = new Image() { Id = "1", Data = ByteString.CopyFrom(imageData), Dtype = "int16" };
            img.Size.Add(frameRowSize);
            img.Size.Add(frameColSize);
            img.Size.Add(numberOfFrames);
            Console.WriteLine("Size Value: " + img.Size);
            Console.WriteLine("CalculateSize: " + img.CalculateSize());
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < numberOfIteration; idx++)
            {
                Stopwatch stopWatchTest = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatchTest.Start();
               var reply = client.SetImage(new ImageMessage() { Ok = img });
                stopWatchTest.Stop();
                TimeSpan tspan = stopWatchTest.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTimeTest = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                tspan.Hours, tspan.Minutes, tspan.Seconds,
                tspan.Milliseconds / 10);
                Console.WriteLine("SetImage Time taken " + elapsedTimeTest);
                Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Ok);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }`
```

I want to find why first call taking 2 minutes but subsequent calls are taking 2 milliSeconds in Linux Debian OS.

Comment: Issue resolved by specifying ip address instead of localhost